# Eliminate extra separators below UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When I set up a table view with 4 rows, there are still extra separators lines (or extra blank cells) below the filled rows.

How would I remove these cells?

[image: image for extra separator lines in UITableView]

Answer (score 1566, accepted):

## Interface builder (iOS 9+)

Just drag a UIView to the table.  In storyboard, it will sit at the top below your custom cells.  You may prefer to name it "footer".

Here it is shown in green for clarity, you'd probably want clear color.

Note that by adjusting the height, you can affect how the "bottom bounce" of the table is handled, as you prefer. (Height zero is usually fine).

[image]

---

To do it programmatically:

## Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

## Objective-C

### iOS 6.1+

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

or if you prefer,

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

### Historically in iOS:

Add to the table view controller...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     // This will create a "invisible" footer
     return CGFLOAT_MIN;
 }
```

and if necessary...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    return [UIView new];

    // If you are not using ARC:
    // return [[UIView new] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I think your descriptions and your code are reversed. Anyway, this worked great for me. I only use "real" footers with grouped tables, so I added if (tableView.style != UITableViewStyleGrouped) { } around your code. Now all my non-grouped tables lose their extra cells, while my grouped tables are unaffected.

Comment: Following my note above, I'll add a warning that if you put any conditions into the the viewForFooterInSection method, be sure that the method returns either a UIView or nil. If you accidentally return void, your app will crash!

Comment: @Mathieu This will works because if the table has a custom footer it will not create "fantom" rows to fill the tableview. So in you will create an empty view to be used as footer and set the height to near 0 (it could not be zero or the iOS will not render it). With this simple trick you will change the default behaviour.

Comment: @j.Costa: Your Solution will work only once while uitableview created. after click on last cell your solution is not more good. please improve your answer.

Comment: @HappyCoding just tested on iOS7 and iOS6.1 and all the solutions worked. I've used 1 UINavigationController and 1 UITableViewController and on cell selection one new UITableViewController was pushed to the UINavigationController. Are you doing something "special" on cell selection method?

Comment: Using `tableFooterView` leaves a separator on the last cell in the row, as the table still anticipates content below that cell. Using the historical way will eliminate that last separator and looks better overall.

Comment: @JamesKuang set a frame with `height = 1` to eliminate the last cell separator to the `tableFooterView`

Comment: The storyboard one works for me, the Swift ways causes premature loading of the contents, and contents will show behind Large Title for a brief moment before bouncing to the bottom of the Large Title.

Comment: HEight has to be zero (can't be 1) to show the very bottom line below the last cell.

Answer (score 130):

Here's another way to do that w/out the grouped table style, and one you'd probably not guess. Adding <strike>a header and</strike> footer to the table <strike>(perhaps one or the other suffices, haven't checked)</strike> causes the separators to disappear from the filler/blank rows.

I stumbled onto this because I wanted a little space at the top and bottom of tables to decrease the risk of hitting buttons instead of a table cell with meaty fingers. Here's a method to stick a blank view in as header and footer. Use whatever height you like, you still eliminate the extra separator lines.

```
- (void) addHeaderAndFooter
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.myTableView setTableHeaderView:v];
    [self.myTableView setTableFooterView:v];
    [v release];
}
```

---

In response to @Casebash, I went back to the code in my app ("AcmeLists" List Manager in iTunes store...) and short-circuited the addHeaderAndFooter method to verify. **Without it**, I have the extra row separators; with the code, I have what you see in this window snap: [no table row separators picture](http://grab.by/1LE2). So I'm not sure why it wouldn't have worked for you. Moreover, it makes sense to me that having any custom footer on a table view would necessarily have to stop drawing row separators for blank rows below it. That would be hideous. For reference, I looked at tables where there were more rows than could be viewed on screen, and then for a table with two rows. In both cases, no extraneous separators.

Perhaps your custom views were not actually added. To check that, set the background color to something other than `clearColor`, e.g., `[UIColor redColor]`. If you don't see some red bars at the bottom of the table, your footer wasn't set.

Comment: You can do this in IB, too. Just drag a UIView at the bottom of the TableView and set the height to 1.

Answer (score 76):

Removing extra separator lines for empty rows in UITableView in **Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.yourTableview.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 35):

I would like to extend **wkw** answer:

Simply adding only footer with height 0 will do the trick. (tested on sdk 4.2, 4.4.1)

```
- (void) addFooter
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self.myTableView setTableFooterView:v];
}
```

or even simpler - where you set up your tableview, add this line:

```
//change height value if extra space is needed at the bottom.
[_tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)]];
```

or even simplier - to simply remove any separators:

```
[_tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];
```

Thanks to **wkw** again :)

Comment: This is the right answer , coz in other methods last row remain with no line separator

Answer (score 23):

### For iOS 7+ using Storyboards

Simply drag a `UIView` into your `UITableView` as the footer. Set the footer view's height to 0.

Answer (score 18):

Try this. It worked for me:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Without ARC
  //self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

  // With ARC, tried on Xcode 5
  self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Swift, add the following code to **viewDidLoad** of the controller that manages the tableview:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //...

    // Remove extra separators
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 14):

### For Swift:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just add an empty footer at the end then it will hide the empty cells but it will also look quite ugly:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

[image]

There is a better approach: add a 1 point line at the end of the table view as the footer and the empty cells will also not been shown anymore.

```
let footerView = UIView()
footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1)
footerView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice input, however no need to make your last cell with a thick separator color at the bottom, instead just make it the same background color of the cell and it also goes away.

Comment: However you prefer. But I think the kinda "not-completed" separator looks quite ugly.

Answer (score 7):

Advancing J. Costa's solution: You can make a global change to the table by putting this line of code:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
```

inside the first possible method (usually in `AppDelegate`, in: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method).

Comment: Be careful with this one, there are cases where your intended footer can be overridden and you'll spend a day or two questioning your sanity.  Also, tableFooterView isn't marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR so the actual behavior could change at any time.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift** works great with:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 7):

just add this code (**Swift**) . .

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: Duplicate of many answers, including the top wiki answer and [Sebastian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626057/1033581)

Answer (score 6):

I know this Question has be accepted answer but i put here different ways for how to hide Extra separator line of `UITableView`.

You can hide `tableView`'s standard separator line, and add your custom line at the top of each cell.

**Update:**

The easiest way to add custom separator is to add simple `UIView` of 1px height:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; /// may be here is clearColor;
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

**OR**

```
    self.tblView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,370) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tblView setTableHeaderView:v];
    [self.tblView setTableFooterView:v];
    [v release];
```

**OR**

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // This will create a "invisible" footer
    return 0.01f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // To "clear" the footer view
    return [[UIView new] autorelease];
}
```

**OR**
The best and simple way i like ever is

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Try any of one;

Answer (score 6):

You may find lots of answers to this question. Most of them around manipulation with  `UITableView`'s `tableFooterView` attribute and this is proper way to hide empty rows. For the conveniency I've created simple extension which allows to turn on/off empty rows from Interface Builder. 
You can check it out from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/freemansion/2b0fa21dfc563d8315ae48c92fa70456) file. I hope it could save a little of your time.

```
extension UITableView {

  @IBInspectable
  var isEmptyRowsHidden: Bool {
        get {
          return tableFooterView != nil
        }
        set {
          if newValue {
              tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
          } else {
              tableFooterView = nil
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tableView.isEmptyRowsHidden = true
```

[image]

Comment: @Yaman I have checked my snippet @ Xcode 12.2, Swift 5 and can confirm that it still works. You can also share part of your code, so it can be easier to determine what you're doing wrong.

Comment: 12.2, see my previous message

Answer (score 5):

uitableview extra separator line hide extra separators lines hide in swift 3.0

```
 self.tbltableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want any separator after the last cell, then you need a close to zero but non-zero height for your footer.

In your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Comment: superb! Worked for me!!

Answer (score 3):

I was using a table view to show a fixed number of fixed height rows, so I simply resized it and made it non-scrollable.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an view with the desired separator color as background color, 100% width,  1px height at the position x0 y-1 to your tableViewCell. Make sure the tableViewCell doesn't clip subviews, instead the tableView should.

So you get a absolut simple and working separator only between existing cells without any hack per code or IB.

Note: On a vertical top bounce the 1st separator shows up, but that shouldn't be a problem cause it's the default iOS behavior.

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate extra separator lines from bottom of UItableview programmatically, just write down following two lines of code and it will remove extra separator from it.

```
tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0.f;
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.f;
```

This trick working for me all the time, try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had some luck implementing a single piece of the accepted answer (iOS 9+, Swift 2.2). I had tried implementing:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

However, there was no effect on my `tableView` - I believe it may have something to do with the fact that I was using `UITableViewController`.

Instead, I only had to override the `viewForFooterInSection` method (I did not set the `tableFooterView` elsewhere):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: .zero)
}
```

This worked fine for a `tableView` with a single section (if you have multiple sections, you need to specify the last one).

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one section, then the quickest and easiest way is to just set the Table View Style from "Plain" to "Grouped". (see image)

[image: TableView Grouped]

If you have more sections, you might need to set the header height to zero (depending on your/your customer's/your project manager's taste)

If you have more sections, and don't want to mess with the headers (even if it is just one line in the simplest case), then you need to set a UIView as a footer, as it was explained in the previous answers)

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 4.0 Extension

Just a little extension for the storyboard:

[image]

```
extension UITableView {
    @IBInspectable
    var hideSeparatorForEmptyCells: Bool {
        set {
            tableFooterView = newValue ? UIView() : nil
        }
        get {
            return tableFooterView == nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy Swift 4 way.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
}
```

If you are having static cells. You can also turn off the separator from Inspector window. (this won't be desirable if you need the separator. In that case use method shown above)
[image: inspector window]

Comment: Setting a new UIView to tableFooterView was already answered 10 times, with better explanations regarding why, better code (you're missing `super.viewDidLoad()`) and is included in the wiki answer on top. As for removing all separators, that's really not what this question is about, so better rollback your last edit and/or delete your answer entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

for **Objective C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // This will remove extra separators from tableview
  self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

for **Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove unwanted space in UITableview you can use below two methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 /Swift 4 /Swift 5 +,   Very Easy and simple way

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      //MARK:- For Hiding the extra lines in table view.
    tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

OR

```
override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
      //MARK:- For Hiding the extra lines in table view.
    tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool)` doesn't exist, and setting the footer each time view will appear is useless. Sorry but your answer is plain wrong and doesn't add any value to the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have added this small tableview extension that helps throughout

```
extension UITableView {
     func removeExtraCells() {
         tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.tables.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 10.0f)];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a `searchbar` in your `view` (to limit the number of results for example), you have to also add the following in `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` and `shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:`

```
controller.searchResultsTable.footerView = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIKit` does not create empty cell when the `tableView` has a `tableFooterView`. So we can make a trick and assign a zero height `UIView` object as footer of the `tableView`.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift (I'm using 4.0), you can accomplish this by creating a custom `UITableViewCell` class, and `overriding` the `setSelected` method. Then the `separator insets` all to **0**. (my main class with the table view has a clear background) color.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // eliminate extra separators below UITableView
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove separator of empty rows by just adding minor height of footer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.01
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are sub-classing the UITableView you need to do this...

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    self.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to recreate the footer each time it is moved to a different superview. Better do the same in `init(frame:style:)`+`init?(coder:)` to guarantee it's done only once.

Answer (score -1):

I just add this line at the ViewDidLoad function and problem fixed.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```