# Can I force a UITableView to hide the separator between empty cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When using a plain-style `UITableView` with a large enough number of cells that the `UITableView` cannot display them all without scrolling, no separators appear in the empty space below the cells. If I have only a few cells the empty space below them includes separators.

Is there a way that I can force a `UITableView` to remove the separators in the empty space? If not I'll have to load a custom background with a separator drawn in for each cell which will make it harder to inherit behavior.

I found a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk), but I can't use a grouped `UITableView` in my implementation.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by defining a footer for the tableview. See this answer for more details:[Eliminate Extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 230):

### For iOS 7.* and iOS 6.1

The easiest method is to set the `tableFooterView` property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

### For previous versions

You could add this to your TableViewController (this will work for any number of sections):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     // This will create a "invisible" footer
     return 0.01f;
 }
```

and **if it is not enough**, add the following code **too**:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    return [UIView new];

    // If you are not using ARC:
    // return [[UIView new] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 156):

### For Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()  // it's just 1 line, awesome!
}
```

Comment: better usage:

 tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero))

Comment: @ayalcinkaya Why is that better than just `UIView()`?

Comment: UIView() is equivalent to UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 67):

Using the link from Daniel, I made an extension to make it more usable:

```
//UITableViewController+Ext.m
- (void)hideEmptySeparators
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:v];
    [v release];
}
```

After some testings, I found out that the size can be 0 and it works as well. So it doesn't add some kind of margin at the end of the table. So thanks wkw for this hack. I decided to post that here since I don't like redirect.

Comment: Do you need to set the background color as well?

Answer (score 24):

**Swift** Version

The easiest method is to set the tableFooterView property:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3 would be:

tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Comment: Or just `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()` (no explicit frame needed).

Answer (score 19):

For Swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

For newest Swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Comment: use CGRect.zero for Swift

Answer (score 8):

If you use iOS 7 SDK, this is very simple.

Just add this line in your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting the table's `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` (in code or in IB) should do the trick.

Comment: If I do that I'll lose all of the separators, which is not the behavior that I am looking for.
The table view automatically draws separators into the empty space if the table does not have enough cells to fill one full screen, but if there are enough cells to fill a screen there are no separators drawn in the empty space below the last cell.

I *could* turn off the separators and just use a cell background with a separator drawn in, but then I am adding another asset to my project which may make updating more difficult in the future.

Comment: I see. I don't believe you can remove separators only where no cells are present. The only other simple solution that comes to mind is to have your cell class inherit from a very minimal UITableViewCell subclass that only draws the separator line. It is an additional piece of complexity, but doesn't need the separate image.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
myTableView.tableFooterView = view;
[view release];
```

Doing it in viewDidLoad. But you can set it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked very well for me for this problem:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

CGRect frame = [self.view frame];
frame.size.height =  frame.size.height - (kTableRowHeight * numberOfRowsInTable);

UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
return footerView; }
```

Where kTableRowHeight is the height of my row cells and numberOfRowsInTable is the number of rows I had in the table.

Hope that helps,

Brenton.