# UITableView - How to show rows only which contains data 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

How can i show `UITableView` Rows only which contains data not the other rows. By default `UITableView` shows 10 rows. If we have data for three rows It will display three rows only
How can I implement this? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to remove the extra separators below a plain style table view, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk/1789714#1789714

Answer (score 32):

You can set a footer view and make it invisible if you want. Separators will appear only for rows which contain data:

```
self.theTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 10.0f)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this ..

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think it is possible to hide the extra separators using a standard way. This behavior is preset.

`Plain` styled tableView shows the `row/separator` even if there are no real rows exist. Only `Grouped` styled tableView shows only the existing rows.

**Edit:** As suggested by others, you can add a footer view to tableView to hide those extra separators.

Comment: you can eliminate the extra separators by [adding a footer view to the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk/1789714#1789714).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I assume you are using Interface Builder.

The easy way:

1. make sure you have chosen your view controller class as both UITableViewDelegate and UITabbleViewDataSource.
2. In the ViewController.h (or whatever its called) add `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>` before the { of the @interface definition. to the class that it must conform to those protocols.
3. Make sure the minimal datasource protocol methods are in the class :

   ```
   – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
   – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
   ```
4. in the – tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  method return the number of desired rows - 3 or by a bit of code to calculate this property
5. in the – tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method do what you need to on the cell and return it. Boilerplate code

   is:

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    }

   cell.text = @"I am a cell";
   return cell;
   }
   ```

N.B. If you are not using Interface Builder do:
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;

Answer (score 0):

Add a static cell that fills the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your viewDidLoad() method.

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can specify the required number of rows in the return parameter of the following function :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return NUMBER_OF_ROWS;
}
```

For more details please go through the Apple documentation of UITableView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: if "data" is your Array/Dictionary with data you can return [data count];