# TableviewCell change unexpectablly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have created an app that contain tableview now i am setting background of that cell and add a view for separator. it look fine but when tebleview scroll than my separator disappear. like this,

First time
[image]
When table scroll
[image]

this is my code for adding tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell * cell;

    SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell...
        UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
        bgview.opaque = YES;
        bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1];
        [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

        UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 1)];
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(74/255.0) green:(89/255.0) blue:(138/255.0) alpha:1];// you can also put image here
        [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

```
   cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
```

Try

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell * cell;

    SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 42, 320, 1)];
        [separatorLineView setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

        UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
        bgview.opaque = YES;
        bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1];
        [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];



    }

    UIView *SPview=[cell viewWithTag:1];
    SPview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];// you can also put image here

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is the frame you set for the view I changed it from 44 to 42 for the seperator line orgin and now it works fine

Comment: Why are you adding a seperator line like this?

Comment: if i do it with UI than it will give separator to all the cell which have not data. so i am adding to separator to only that cell which contain data. If any other better method than plz let me know.

Comment: Still same problem is occurring.

Comment: How can i put this in word.... you are savior ...... thank you very very very much.

Comment: @Kane : see I used viewWithTag method.Use it to update view components ,otherways the view will be allocated and added one above another whenever you scroll

Answer (score 0):

Move the configuring of the cell outside of

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}

// everything else
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell * cell;

    SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    bgview.opaque = YES;
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(74/255.0) green:(89/255.0) blue:(138/255.0) alpha:1];// you can also put image here
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you try comment out [cell setBackgroundView:bgview]; and let me know what is happening there?

Comment: If i comment out [cell setBackgroundView:bgview]; still the behavior is same just BG is white.

Comment: what is the height of the cell?

Comment: Its default height so i think 44.

Comment: ok just remove cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil]; and if(cell == nil) block. every time create new cell and configure and return it. if still problem persists then comment all configur. just crate and return cell. If still problem persists delete the app from simulator clean xcode and run it again

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're not configuring your cell each time you get a new one. You should populate your cell each time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Try changing your code to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell * cell;

    SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    bgview.opaque = YES;
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.0) green:(230/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 1)];
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(74/255.0) green:(89/255.0) blue:(138/255.0) alpha:1];// you can also put image here
        [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410442/uitableview-how-to-show-rows-only-which-contains-data).

First add separator thru the xib file and than put this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 10.0f)] autorelease];
```