# Hide remove separator line if UITableViewCells are empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` and I have only 3 rows in it, and I can see those 3 rows. The problem is the cells that are empty: I can see lines there. I don't want to see those lines.

Any idea how to remove those lines?

Below is image for what I am looking for.

### [image: Image Link]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: to create a screen shot, press command+shift+4, then the mouse cursor will be changed to a plus symbol, click and drag the required area,when U release the mouse button, the image will be captured and saved in the desktop.

Comment: I love how the background for the screenshot is the SO page with similar questions, as if to say "Oh  lords of SO, please forgive me. I did search, I really really did" :D

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can hide `UITableView`'s standard separator line by using any one of the below snippets of code.
The easiest way to add a custom separator is to add a simple `UIView` of 1px height:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // set color as you want.
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

**OR**

```
    self.tblView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,370) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tblView setTableHeaderView:v];
    [self.tblView setTableFooterView:v];
    [v release];
```

**OR**

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // This will create a "invisible" footer
    return 0.01f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // To "clear" the footer view
    return [[UIView new] autorelease];
}
```

**OR**

And also check [nickfalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461000/603977), it is very short and helpful too.
And you should also try this single line,

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Not sure but it's working in all the version of iOS that I checked, with iOS 5 and later, up to iOS 7.

Comment: Just a note, using the second option will remove the separator line for the last cell, which may not be what you want. The first option will retain the separator line, though I recommend just using the following code: `[self.tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];` for an invisible footer as described in an answer below.

Comment: @iPatel I am using the third option, when I focus the last table cell, the seperator appears...any fix for this?

Comment: Would someone mind giving a little bit of context for the first option? I'm not sure where that's supposed to go.

Comment: @Pepedou your modifying a cell, so if you want it to be applied to a single instance then you'd do in the `cellForAtIndex` or if you want it applied to a *tableViewCell` class then you would do it in it's class so all it's instances would be affected...

Answer (score 147):

Even simpler than Andrey Z's reply:
Simply make a bogus tableFooterView in your UITableView class:

```
self.tableFooterView = [UIView new]; // to hide empty cells
```

and Swift:

`tableFooterView = UIView()`

Comment: it does not work in iOS 7. @iPatel solution works very well.

Comment: [self.tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];

Comment: @RedDevil It works fine in iOS 7 for me.

Comment: but that looks ugly something like in chat... it shows emppty cell and blank space...

Comment: @RedDevil have you tested it, it;s working in iOS 7.0.

Comment: It does NOT work if you don't want to have the last cell's separator visible. It will remove every subsequent cell's separator, but for the last one you have, the separator will still be there. Use @iPatel's third choice for best results.

Comment: This worked for me on iOS 8. With Swift do tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Comment: Also works on iOS 9.

Comment: We can do that also by using only storyboard : Drag a `UIView` to the bottom of your `UITableView`

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer for swift & iOS 9.  This works for tableviews of the `.Plain` variety.

```
 tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: This solution was already provided over two years previously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461000/603977

Answer (score 7):

Transparent `UIView` as a `tableView` footer with 1px height will do the trick.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:v];
```

Comment: OR :  Swift  on viewDidLoad()    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 6):

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Code-only answers, and one-liners even more so, should really have a bit of text explaining what the code does.

Comment: This solution was already provided over two years previously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461000/603977

Answer (score 3):

Use this Code for remove separator line for empty cells.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// This will create a "invisible" footer
return 0.01f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [UIView new];

    // If you are not using ARC:
    // return [[UIView new] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: After using this the separator for last row is not visible. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Just returning an empty `UIView()` in `viewForFooterInSection` worked for me:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code:

```
self.tblView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
if ([self.tblView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
{
    [self.tblView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
// write in view did load
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tableForBrands.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: This solution was already provided earlier the same year: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461000/603977

Answer (score 0):

None of suggested answers were suitable for my similar problem. Implementing this method in tableView delegate finally worked:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: This disables all separators. Not a solution to the problem at all. Also you call this for every display of cell - really not a good solution. Put this in viewDidLoad if you want to run the code.

Comment: This removes the lines below: that was the core question. If you check the OP's attached image: there in violet it says: "I want to remove those below lines". You can always draw separators on populated cells. And simply puting this in viewDidLoad actually does not work in iOS > 7 due to under the hood bugs in layoutSubviews of UITableViewCell. Even setting the separator color to clearColor of backgroundColor of tableView does not work. Even putting this in cellForRowAtIndexPath does not work... because layoutSubviews happens afterwards: just before cell is displayed.

Comment: I just tried it. It removes all separators, as expected, since it's an attribute of the tableView and not the cells.

Comment: There are two types of tableViews: plain and grouped. It works with one type and does not with the other. At least on some versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards you can just drag and drop an UIView into your UITableView below your cells and set its height to 0. (Have only tested in an iOS 8 project)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table view to be grouped instead of plain - this changes the look a bit but at least removes the extra lines.

I had this exact problem and ended up changing to grouped views. Looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Some of previous suggestions contain a BIG conceptual error:

if You do:

[cell addSubview: ....

even time a cell is "reused", you will add a new subview for the divider!

avoid it in two ways:

a) use a TAG, and:
   1) ask for a subview for that tag 
      let divider = cell.viewWithTag(TAG) ...
   2) if present, do NOT add another subview
   3) if NOT present add AND tag it.

b) create a custom view and ADD your custom divider in "init" "awakeFromNib" of custom cell.

code for a):

```
 if let divider = cell.viewWithTag(DIVIDER_TAG) as? UIView{
            // nothing.. eventually change color bases in IndexPath...
        }else{
            let frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.height-1, cell.frame.width, 1)
            divider.tag = DIVIDER_TAG
            divider.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.addSubview(divider)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
let separatorLineView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableview.bounds.width,0.5))
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor
cell!.contentView.addSubview(separatorLineView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution:
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

Worked on Xcode 7.2

Comment: This solution was already provided over three years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461000/603977