# Hide blank rows under last cell in static Table View Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a segue from my Root View Controller to a little static Table View Controller. It's supposed to have only six options (it's static), yet there seems to be more rows shown below the last item.

The table view content is set to "static cells" and I've created a show segue from one of my Root View Controller's Table View Cell's to this Table View Controller.

How can I get rid of the endless list of rows under the "Every Year" option?

[image]

EDIT:

This is different from [Hide remove separator line if UITableViewCells are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460772/how-to-hide-remove-separator-line-if-cells-are-empty) because it has a much more elegant solution - see below.

Comment: Did you look at the second answer to the other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set tableview's style "Grouped".

- Select tableview in storyboard and go to Attribute Inspector.
- From the Style option you need to select "Grouped" (By default "Plain" is selected)

[image]

This will hide endless list of rows.

Answer (score 2):

Do following.

[image]

It will hide all blank rows from tableview.

Answer (score 2):

put this in `viewDidLoad` method, it will hide the bank cells.

for swift 2:
`tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`