# IOS heightForRowAtIndexPath, setting height for empty cells

Tags: ios

i am setting the heightForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /* Contains the string */
    NSString *allStrings = [self convertMainData:indexPath];


    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [allStrings sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}
```

This gets called when the table is not empty, and the size gets calculated correctly, now the issue is that if there is data in the Table, all the cells get their height changed:

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3025/yrgt.png

I have tried checking for this in the delegate method

```
if([tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath] == nil)
   return 20;
```

But this returns an error, i have also tried wrapping it in != nil, but that has no effect, so how do i leave the empty rows at the default height ?

Comment: Your image link isn't valid and I don't understand your problem statement at all. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: What do you mean by empty rows?

Comment: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3025/yrgt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the cell displays allStrings as its content.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /* Contains the string */
    NSString *allStrings = [self convertMainData:indexPath];

    if(allStrings.length == 0)
    return 20.0f; // return default height. Adjust accordingly

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [allStrings sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}
```

Comment: @JohnDOe, you need to describe what you want more clearly. It's not clear what you mean be empty cells.

Comment: check if you set the UITableView's rowHeight property somewhere else in code or xib. The height of the empty cells (indexes greater than what you return in numberOfRowsInSection:)is taken from that property.

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling empty cells is actually just lines drawn by the table view below your actual cells. The spacing of these lines is determined by the height of your final cell. So if you want a specific spacing, you've got to insert a blank cell as your last row and return the specific height for that row in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

So, the solution proposed by Max will work. You've just got to add another entry in your data model as the last item such that `[self convertMainData:indexPath]` returns an empty string or `nil` for that item. If you need more details, please share the details of your data model and view controller's data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

An empty tableview footer is the answer. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377569/605197) for implementation details.