# Tableview separators appearing in empty cells

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I've got a popover that displays a bunch of settings in a tableview. The user can drill down on options, and obviously return to the main settings screen.

The first time I open the popover, a separator is shown below each filled cell. When I drill down and return to the main settings screen, the separator is shown on all cells, filled or not. What is happening?

[image: Tableview on first display]
[image: Tableview on second display, showing extra separators]

This is how I create cells:

```
- (BTDrillDownTableViewCell*)dequeueCell
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTDrillDownTableViewCell";
    BTDrillDownTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BTDrillDownTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And this is the implementation of the BTDrillDownTableViewCell:

```
@implementation BTDrillDownTableViewCell

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you set custom height for cell?
Do lines appear after scrolling?

Comment: No custom height set for cells, and the lines don't appear after scrolling. They only appear when I drill down and return.

Answer (score 0):

When returning the following morning, I found the solution in another question:

[Eliminate extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk)