# How can I detect the onclick below footer after I remove empty cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

I have set the frame of the tableFooterView to have a height of 0. 
**I want to detect the click for below the footer in empty cells**

**I have got conditions like below** and want to handle click on clicking gray part of below image
[image]

[Eliminate extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Consider placing a clear `UIView` in the footer, and instead of making it `CGRectZero` making it a reasonable size, and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that clear `UIView`.

Comment: how can i set the remaining empty cells as the tableFooterView . How is it possible to calculate the height of tableFooterView with increasing and decreasing the remaining cells