# Storyboard static table view too many rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have added a static table view to my storyboard. In the tableview there are 3 static cells.

[image]

When i run this in simulator i get this:

[image]

As you can see i get too many rows now. Why? Isn't it suppose to be static as in displaying 3 rows as in the storyboard?

Comment: add this line in view did load  'self.tabelview.tableFooterView = [UIView new];' hope it help..!

Comment: Add a footer view into the storyboard'

Answer (score 3):

## Update :

For people that wants to keep separator but not those extra ones after the cells ends do this :

**Objective C :**

```
self.tableView.footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

**Swift 3.0+**

```
tableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Also, after this you do not need to remove separators, you can keep them, as it is.

## Original Answer :

Those are not Static cells they are the Separators generated by the tableview.

For your confusion i tried the same thing with the static cells each having a background colour and this is what i got

[image]

Hence i can say is that those arnt cells, they are the separators which are making it appear as if there are cells to it. Check the separators to nil to make the effect go away..
Here
[image]

And then this is what i get

[image]

Comment: I want separators for my cells tho, but only for the 3 cells ive added. Is this possible?

Comment: You can add a `view` with height 1 and a background colour of your desire inside the 3 cells and turn off separators. That will create the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

By default, UITableView show empty cell with separate line. They are empty cells. You can hide them by following topic [Eliminate extra separators below UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I want to design my tableview and cells in storyboard, i thought that was what u did with a static table view, do i really have to use delegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, not for just static tableviews. You need to add a blank tableview footerView. Swift:

`tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`