# How to delete the empty cells that i don't use in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got a toEat array:

var toEat = ["apple"]

In addition, the user can add more fruits to the array while running the app, for example:

var toEat = ["apple", "banana"]

The array has nothing more except apple and banana, so why when I run the app I get empty cells? How can I delete it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminate Extra separators below UITableView - in iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk) – Even if that thread uses Objective-C code (for historical reasons :), the solutions are the same!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this line of code:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, I'll give the credit to @mikle94 because he answered first :)