# Hiding separator for a single tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a UITableView with 2 static cells:

[image: TableView]

And I would like to remove the second separator because it is ugly. I found lots of articles abuot that theme but non of them worked on iOS 9. (eg. `mySecondCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeSeparatorInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 999)`

EDIT:

Thanks for the footer idea, it worked. I just dropped it in and set the height to 0, and the color to default.

Comment: Try adding `mySecondCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero` prior to the `UIEdgeSeparatorInsetsMake`. Alternatively, have a look at the `UIView` "footer" solution [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk/5377569#5377569).

Comment: try this..http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877725/5362916

Comment: Wow, the footer thing worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually disable the separators and add my own `UIViews` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That works most reliably and don't have to fix this in every new iOS version.